# RFID data transfer rates?

Tags: rf, rfid, modulation

I'm learning about RFID and am trying to figure out what the data rates are for the different types of RFID technologies.

I've learned that there are three different frequencies tags and readers operate on:

```
LF - 125-134 kHz
HF - 13.56 MHz
UHF - 850-960 MHz
```

There are also a number of different modulation schemes used, such as:

```
PSK
FSK
ASK
```

I'm thinking the data rates are dependent mostly upon the frequency being used (LF, HF, or UHF), but does the modulation scheme also play a factor in the data rate?

How would one go about determining the data rates (such as in bits per second) for the different types of RFID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the standards documents for each one.

I know that in LF at least, the data rate is normally a simple divider from the carrier frequency. A 128 kHz carrier might be divided by a factor of 32 or 16 to create a data rate 4 or 8 kbps, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Nate said:

> By reading the standards documents for each one.
>
> I know that in LF at least, the data rate is normally a simple divider
>   from the carrier frequency. A 128 kHz carrier might be divided by a
>   factor of 32 or 16 to create a data rate 4 or 8 kbps, for example.

Yes, and yes!

For UHF systems, the data rate is typically 40 kbps, but the standard specifies data rates up to 640 kbps.

FSK/ASK/PSK in RFID can be a little confusing. For UHF RFID systems, the physical layer (PHY) uses ASK/PSK backscatter. At design time, the engineer chooses to produce ASK or PSK backscatter by selecting the impedance mismatch. From here, FSK encoding can be produced to generate a subcarrier to carry the data.